# Is it possible to set a Membership Status Override for a Membership Type?

Tags: civimember

I'm doing some testing and investigation into using CiviCRM for convention memberships.

These need to be able to be upgraded.

There is no membership type upgrade in CivCRM.

You can only memberships.

But it occurred to me that perhaps I could use Membership Status to hold what the current ACTUAL membership Status is.

The problem is, that I want membership Status to be be based on the Membership type, not the date that the membership /s are valid for. And there's no way to have any other criteria than dates.

Then I saw that when adding memberships manually, you can set a Status Override. This is probably exactly what I want. Except I can't see any way of setting a Status Override in a normal membership.  ie. IF someone buys a membership online, I can't have that membership THEY bought have a status override. Is there a way anyone can think to do this?

Comment: you could try out civirules for that

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're aiming to do here.  Membership is for a defined period of time and status relates to those dates and payments etc.  You want the status to be based on the type ... anything else?   The Membership functionality may not be a good fit for your needs so step back from the details of membership type/status/overrides and describe the bigger picture of what you're trying to do and we may be able to help.